# cannot view azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In my current company a previous developer left who setup within Azure devOps a pipeline connecting to GitHub which builds and releases an API (service).

I cannot view any builds, logs,  pipelines etc. I am assuming this is because he has deleted it?
I have owner credentials on azure.
Does this mean  he has deleted the pipeline? Is there away to be able to restore the previous work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to restore deleted pipelines and builds using UI.
**BUT,** there's a way to do so using scripts.

1. the script will only work if the definitions were deleted less than 4 week ago
2. You need to create a personal access token (PAT) in the account you use for azure DevOps
3. there's no need to encode the $accountName, $projectName and $definitionNameToRecover variables. Values containing spaces will work.
4. the release will recover the definition od release but not it's history.

you can find the script here. ----> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aseemb/how-to-undelete-a-deleted-release-definition

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you could not access the DevOps the service deployed from. The account you logged in Azure needed to be added to the DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx) that deployed the service.

You could add the account you logged in Azure to DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx) and try again.

Comment: I understand that point. The Devops Organisation resource is not visible, i haven't got the credentials to view or add my account details to the resource.